# cpufreq: scaling broken on i7-1185G7, kernel 5.8.0

Tags: cpu, intel, cpu-frequency

I bought a laptop with a fairly recent CPU: the [i7-1185G7](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/processors/core/i7-processors/i7-1185g7.html).

On a fresh Ubuntu 20.20 installation (Linux 5.8.0-33-generic), I noticed the laptop was very slow.

I poked around the `intel_pstate` parameters in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq` and made the following observations:

- The default `scaling_governor` is `powersave` for all cores. In this mode, the CPU is borderline unusable as it keeps all cores running at `400Mhz` except for short bursts of turbo boosts, where they go to `4.8GHz` and then back.
- Setting the `scaling_governor` to `performance` for a core makes it run at nominal `3GHz`, turbo-boosting to `4.8GHz` for as long as it can, with no reason (laptop idle) until some cutoff is reached (`thermald` is my theory).

The CPU has 4 physical, 8 logical cores. Setting 4 logical cores to `performance` and 4 to `powersave` drains the battery at ~1%/min. So I get ~1h40m of battery life. Disabling turbo boosts improves this a little bit.

Next I disabled frequency scaling in the BIOS and linux defaulted to use `acpi-cpufreq`. With this driver, all cores are always at `400MHz` by default. And I need to set the min/max frequencies I want myself. They usually stay at minimum. This defeats the purpose of having automatic frequency scaling at all.

My question is: can I have purely hardware-controlled frequency scaling? I would like to disable both drivers and have the CPU make its own frequency scaling decision. Is that a possibility? Secondly, where should I best report this behavior, arguably in `intel_pstate`?

Answer (score 2):

I also have problem with my brand new DELL latitude 5420 (2021) with the same CPU (i7-1185G7) and Linux.

I temporary resolve the issue by running the commands below after system boot:

```
sudo rmmod intel_rapl_msr 
sudo rmmod processor_thermal_device 
sudo rmmod processor_thermal_rapl 
sudo rmmod intel_rapl_common 
sudo rmmod intel_powerclamp

sudo modprobe intel_powerclamp
sudo modprobe intel_rapl_common 
sudo modprobe processor_thermal_rapl 
sudo modprobe processor_thermal_device
sudo modprobe intel_rapl_msr
```

Comment: thanks for this answer; do you have any idea why this works? is it perhaps resetting something that BIOS sets incorrectly? I also found out that it works for me but only when run after Xorg and not via systemd at boot.